# Why Eventlog doesn't show the "key"-icon?

Tags: windows, vb.net

Environment: VS2017 on Windows 10, target framework .NET4.0

I develop an application which writes also entries in the `eventlog`. Here's my problem:

```
EventLog.WriteEntry("Application", "sample entry (type 'Information')", EventLogEntryType.Information, 0)
```

Code sample above works fine, there's a new entry in the application event log with  an `Information-icon` in front of it. Same on `EventLogEntryType.Error` and `EventLogEntryType.Warning`. Nice 'Error'- and 'Warning'-icons in front of it. 
But if I try this:

```
EventLog.WriteEntry("Application", "sample entry (type 'SuccessAudit')", EventLogEntryType.SuccessAudit, 0)
```

in event log is a new entry but with the false icon type `Information` in front of it and NOT the nice `Key-icon`. But why?

Comment: I've only ever seen them in the "Security" log but your writing to "Application"

Comment: Yes, thats right. I trie'd also with an custom log and it also doesn't work. But on WinXP with a custom log it worked without any problems.